# copy products from category to other category

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

Using magento 1.9.1

I want to copy products from different category to another category. I got the following:

```
    INSERT INTO multi_catalog_category_product
    SELECT <target_category_id> as multi_category_id, tablea.product_id,    tablea.position
    FROM `multi_catalog_category_product` tablea
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `multi_catalog_category_product` tableb
   ON tablea.product_id = tableb.product_id
   AND tableb.category_id = <target_category_id>
   WHERE tablea.`category_id` = <source_category_id> AND tableb.position is   NULL
```

It is working. But I was wondering if I did not forgot a table and if this is best practice.